# Is there any alternative to ANT's XMLTask to do XML replacements without changing the file's structure?

Tags: java, groovy, jython

When using XMLParser of Groovy (and smiliar APIs) to change a text-node's content in an XML, it will loose the overall structure while parsing the file and thus when written back to a file. I.e. the spaces change, comments are removed, dtd-references are stripped.

There exists an ANT library called [XMLTask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) that allows to do simple replacements with the help of XPath and maintains the overall structure of the file. Is there some similar and easy-to-use API in Java, Groovy, Jython or friends that allows this?
Preferably Groovy, so it integrates well with Gradle.

Comment: note that XMLTask will often fail on non-Oracle/Sun JREs so alternatives must still be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just stick xmltask on the classpath, and use groovy's AntBuilder. There's an example of [this here I believe](http://josefbetancourt.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/transform-xml-with-groovy-and-xmltask/)

Comment: Broken link, this is the updated one: http://octodecillion.com/blog/transform-xml-with-groovy-and-xmltask/

Answer (score 1):

I found that the DOMBuilder in groovy actually keeps the structure, comments and schema references as from the input file:

```
import groovy.xml.DOMBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import static javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.*
import javax.xml.xpath.*

def doc = DOMBuilder.parse(new StringReader(new File("ejb-jar.xml").getText()), false, false).documentElement

use(groovy.xml.dom.DOMCategory) {
    nodes= doc.xpath( "//session/ejb-name[text()='EmployeeFacade']/../description", NODESET)
    println nodes.getLength()
    nodes.each{ 
        it.value = "TEST"
    }
}

def result = XmlUtil.serialize(doc)
println result
```

Did not expect that to work...

Answer (score 0):

There are XPath matchers in plain java too http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html

See the `Listing 7. XPath query that uses namespaces` for an example.
The main theory is that you write a matcher and loop through the results.

Comment: I can't see how this relates to my question. How do I make sure the formatting of the output file is kept (including indentation, comments, etc.)? It just is an XPath library for accessing elements. Says nothing about saving it back in "unaltered" formatting?